# How does WiX determine file version?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, version

I ran into an issue that some of the files in my installation were not replaced on upgrade. The problem is not too severe yet, but I would like to avoid it in the future. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599(v=vs.85).aspx files with higher version are always used. I considered using a [CompanionFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367997(v=vs.85).aspx) to force upgrade the relevant files. But I would like to know what file should be used as the companion parent. Does it have to be an exe or dll? I am asking because I found online (in [WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://books.google.cz/books?id=IxD182o_jQMC&pg=PT233&dq=wix%20minversion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigx4WcqcDMAhUmP5oKHaRTDn8Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=wix%20minversion&f=false)) an example of FileSearch on .txt file with MinVersion and MaxVersion. Can txt files be also versioned? And is there anywhere a list of file types WiX searches for version? I did not find anything like it.

Answer (score 0):

If your product has one main exe it is probably best to use that since it logically follows that your new version should always put the new exe there since the exe will have the new version as its file version. In reality, it doesn't matter what file you companion file reference as long as you know it will always be installed (have a higher version) than the previous installation.

I don't think you can version a txt file and probably the version info in the file search is ignored if the file has no version.